# Three.JS - Raycasting on custom mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, raycasting

I'm currently trying to raycast a custom created mesh in three.js. While raycasting works like a charm for some imported meshes, it just doesn't seem to work at all with my custom mesh.

After researching for quite a while I found some typical issues for custom raycasting and tried to fix them (updateMatrixWorld, double side material, ... - see code below).

I'm using the following function for my raycasting:

```js
mouse.x = ((e.clientX - container.offsetLeft) / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -((e.clientY - container.offsetTop) / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;

rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
var intersect = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.getObjectByName('loaded_object').children, true); // working


mesh_1.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
mesh_1.updateMatrixWorld();
var intersect_custom = rayCaster.intersectObjects([mesh_1], true); // not working
```

While the first intersect is working as expected, my custom intersect somehow doesn't work at all - it always returns an empty array.
Am I right with my assumption that the problem must be my custom mesh?

So here's how I created my custom mesh:

```js
material_k1.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
var singleGeometry_1 = new THREE.Geometry();
var mesh_1 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_1, material_k1);

meshes[i].updateMatrix();
singleGeometry_1.merge(meshes[i].geometry, meshes[i].matrix);

mesh_1.updateMatrix();
singleGeometry_1.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
singleGeometry_1.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
mesh_1 = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry_1, material_k1);
```

What else might be the problem? I'm really wondering especially since it only seems to be not working with my custom mesh.

Comment: When and how do you add vertices and faces to your mesh? Would be good to provide a working live code example, showing the problem (code snippets, jsfiddle, codepen etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem myself after trying everything for a long time. My code was fine except for one line which was missing. 
After adding

```
mesh_1.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

my code worked as expected. 
 Seems like the bounding sphere is also needed for raycasting.

Thanks for your help! Hopefully this helps anyone with the same problem.